# How can i solve this Exception that occurs when i migrate my Voyager (admin panal ) BadMethodCallException date_time_set does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

```
BadMethodCallException  : Method 
Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::date_time_set does not exist.

at
```

//
    C:\wamp64\www\NewsApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support
    \Traits\Macroable.php:104
    100|      */
    101|     public function __call($method, $parameters)
    102|     {
    103|         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {

> 104|             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
>       105|              'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, 
>       $method
>       106|             ));
>       107|         }
>       108|

```
Exception trace:

1   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::__call("date_time_set")

C:\wamp64\www\NewsApp\database\migrations
  \2019_10_28_194406_create_posts_table.php:20

2   CreatePostsTable::{closure} 
  (Object(Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint))

C:\wamp64\www\NewsApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src
    \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder.php:166

Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

//2019_10_28_194406_create_posts_table.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void'category_id'
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->date_time_set('Date');


        $table->text('image') ->nullable();
        $table->integer('votes_up') -> nullable();
        $table->integer('votes_down') ->nullable();
        //relationships
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
}
}
```

Comment: Kindly share the content of `2019_10_28_194406_create_posts_table.php` cos it appears you're calling a method on BluePrint that doesn't exist

Comment: added 2019_10_28_194406_create_posts_table.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrong on migration file with line

```
$table->date_time_set('Date');
```

Change to:

```
$table->dateTime("date");
```